# Regex to match everything except a list of characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I want to match a line containing everything except the specified characters `[I|V|X|M|C|D|L]`.

```
new Regex(@"^(.*) is (?![I|V|X|M|C|D|L].*)$")
```

should match everything except the characters mentioned in the `OR` list.

Should match -

```
name is a
```

Should not match -

```
edition is I
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^[^IVXMCDL]*$
```

This will match the start of the string, followed by zero or more characters *other than* those specified in the character class, followed by the end of the string. In other words, it will not match any a string which contains those characters.

Also note that depending on how you're using it, you could probably use a simpler pattern like this:

```
[IVXMCDL]
```

And reject any string which matches the pattern.

Comment: But `*` will match any number of characters. I need it to match only one character.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta The `*` means that it can contain any number of strings *other than* those in the character class (because the character class is negated with `^`). In other words, it cannot contain a single character which is in the class.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `|` in this case, just use `^[^IVXMCDL]*$`

```
^[^IVXMCDL]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/s1IV5-b3SuuaN9a2)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private  bool IsValid(String input)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            // Here we call Regex.Match.
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[^IVXMCDL]*$");

            // Here we check the Match instance.
            if (match.Success)
            {
               isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isValid = false;
            }

          return isValid;
        }
```